# what info is in datum value and how can we extract it

Tags: datum, datum-value, datum-hash, bytes

In the case for `spend` purposes e.g.

```
Value: {"fields": [{"bytes": "10dc9481577ae0ac7a2b828bae9f2ba163b79ce73069d75fd609bc88"}, {"bytes": "a20a"}], "constructor": 0}
```

what kind of information is found in the first and second bytes field, and how does one extract this?